# How to print the sql exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, exception, sqlexception

I just want to print the sql exception in my code. the statement is like this

```vb
Catch Msg As Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  'On any Exception set the connection false
  ConnectDb = False
  writeLogdbconn(" in sql exception ") 'this method will print the message in text file at some directory location
  Throw
```

I want to print the sql exception here. when I try this:

```
writeLogdbconn("in try - catch " & Msg)
```

gets the error

> & operand is not defined for strings and sql exception.

Please suggest what should I used here for print the sql exception.

Comment: i am not quite sure what you need but you can always do something like try/catch and in catch put in console.writeline(err.description)

Comment: thanks  @nocturnal , but i need to print in log file . anyways i got solution . thankyou for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Msg` is a class, not a string. You probably need to use `Msg.Message`.

```
writeLogdbconn("in try - catch " & Msg.Message)
```

You can also look at the example code on the MSDN page for [Exception.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: thanks @srutzky for information , yes it helps and resolve the prob

Comment: hi @srutzky , could you provide me link for do that. actually i am new to this site.